# How to display the large text if this method "titleForHeaderInSection" returns in iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am unable to display the total information if the results are nil in iPhone.

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([customerList count] == 0)
    {
        return @"Could not find any doctor with your search. Please try again.";
    }
    return @"";
}

I Declared the table as below
        myTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,370) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

Here I can display the text upto ... "Could not find any doctor with your......" How can I show full or total information, Please suggest the solution. 
Thanking You,
Madan Mohan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Try out this delegate and pass on a view with multilines label.. it will work...

hAPPY cODING...

Comment: Take a multiline label in the above delegate method and add it to a view. both must have transparent background. then write your text in that label and return the view for the above delegate... hope its now clear.

Comment: this works but it does not have same appearance as default view.

Answer (score 1):

the method [(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/numberOfSectionsInTableView:) delivers how many sections are present in the current UTableView datasource.

if your datasource is empty, it will provide "0". therefore, your titleForHeaderInSection-method will never be called because of that zero.

if you really want to display that message inside a section header, try something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if([customerList count == 0]) return 1;
    else return [[customerList getSections] count];  // or how ever you get the total of sections in your datasource
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    if([customerList count] == 0) return 0;
    else return [[customerList getSection:section] count]  // or whatever you have implemented :)
}
```

Comment: ou, guess you'll have to use a combination of Suriyas and my answer ;)

Comment: MM does not want to use multiple sections he just want to make the text of his sectionheader larger which gives... if used with default..